# How to quickly add a column to a file with lua

Tags: file, lua

I have a lua script interface to our main application.

One of the scripts writes a point cloud file, which is a series of tab separated columns, the first three being x, y, z coordinates of a point in space, and the following columns each a particular result at that point.

I have a case where there are over 20 million points and a large number of results. The current script reads all the results into memory and writes each line at a time, having the result for each column in memory. This is too heavy on memory for the case as described, so I have switched to writing it on a column by column basis.

The way I am currently doing this is to first write the coordinates, as these I know fit into memory, then individually get each result vector, and add that vector to the file using the following code:

```
local append_column = function (filename, varname, data) 
-- assumes every column has the same number of values    
-- data is zero indexed! 

  if data==nil  then   
    do return end
  end 
  newfile = assert(io.open("temp.txt", "w"))
  count=0 
  for line in io.lines(filename) do               
    newfile:write(line)    
    if count==0 then
      newfile:write(varname, "\t")              
    elseif data[count-1] == nil then     
      newfile:write("\t")                 
    else      
      newfile:write(data[count-1], "\t")      
    end    
    newfile:write("\n")
    count = count + 1    
  end
  assert(newfile:close())
  copy_file("temp.txt", filename)
  os.remove("temp.txt")
end
```

my copy_file function is reasonably fast, as I can read the input file in chunks with

```
f:read(BUFSIZE, "*line")
```

and write the new file in chunks the same size. The line-by-line processing of the append_column function is pretty slow. Any ideas how I could speed this up? I suppose those conditionals inside the main loop aren't ideal, so I'll look at that in the meantime, but if there's a better general approach, it would be great to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things come to mind:

1. Avoid multiple writes and build a concatenated string first and then write it with one call.
2. Pre-format each file to have enough space for the column you are adding and simply write the data you need without re-writing the rest of the content. Since your lines are fixed-length, you can use `seek` to go to the proper location, add your column values, seek to the next one, and so on.

Comment: Multiple writes result in less memory usage but longer execution time. A singe concatenated string results in a lot of memory usage and a faster execution. Choose what fits your needs.

Comment: The question was about speeding up the processing and since the lines are probably short (based on the description), it's worth testing doing fewer writes.

Comment: "The current script reads all the results in memory" "This is too heavy on memory"

Comment: You are only concatenating fields for one line at a time; after that particular lines is printed, the memory for that line is no longer used (and the line is short per the description).

Comment: actually I think Paul has an idea - with 1) he is talking about buffering the output during the column append (I presume) which is not the same as reading all the results into memory. I'm not sure 2) would work though - surely I I write into the end of each line I would be overwriting the beginning of the next line? Besides that, my lines are not fixed length (they are fixed number of columns but the size of the numbers varies)

Comment: Pauls point 2) is actually pretty good if the lines are of a known length. I  had missed the comment "Pre format each file to have enough space...."  this is a pretty good approach and I'll look into it.